# Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: RUNTIME0031: Failed to locate the operation for this SOAP call

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client, wsimport

I am getting following error while invoking the web service through the code generated by wsimport.

The same code works with java7 but throwing the error when using java 6.

any help on this is much appreciated.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: RUNTIME0031: Failed to locate the operation for this SOAP call.
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:111)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.getSync(Unknown Source)
at com.test.wsclient.WSTestClient.main(WSTestClient.java:35)
```

Comment: Did you generate the code using Java 6 or Java 7?

Comment: I have also generated the code with java6 and has the same issue.